# Why does the YouTube IFrame API for iOS devices send messages with a youtubeplayer:// protocol?

Tags: swift, youtube

I am trying to use pieces of the [YouTubePlayerKit](https://github.com/SvenTiigi/YouTubePlayerKit) for a project I am working on. It looks like the library does the following:

1. Creates a player instance from a videoId
2. Creates a webview to load the video in
3. Evaluates some JS to get the video loaded

Re: the 3rd step, I was browsing the source code and i saw this function:

```js
// Send YouTubePlayer Event with optional data
function sendYouTubePlayerEvent(event, data) {
    var locationHref = 'youtubeplayer://' + event;
    if (data) {
        locationHref = locationHref + '?data=' + data;
    }
    window.location.href = locationHref
}
```

What I can't understand is, why are they using a `youtubeplayer://` protocol? Is it inferring where to send events based on the name of the player class? Just for reference, I was looking at [this library](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper) as well, and they use the protocol `ytplayer://`. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

`ytplayer://` is the start of a `URL`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app

https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/

From the looks of your code it would ultimately look like

`youtubeplayer://play?data=fghdfgjhdfgjdfgj`

With `fghdfgjhdfgjdfgj` being some data object.

`window.location` would take that URL and do something with it like set the location of the current view or direct the webview to that website.

If you look at the code for the "Widget Code Along" You will find a good example for this setup, they only glance over it in the video but a

`Link` in a Widget uses a `URL` to open the detail view of a character.

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=yv6so7ie